# Changing firewall setting

Tags: firewall

What is the difference between allowing an IP that ends with 32 after /
For e.g. what is the difference between these 2 IP addresses?

```
282.72.129.206/31
282.72.129.206/32
```

I will like to confirm that if I remove /31 there will be no connectivity problem.

Comment: Depends on whether `282.72.129.207` wants to talk to you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because absent a crystal ball there is no way we can answer it for you. The answer requires intimate knowledge of your environment that nobody here can possibly have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is the amount of bits that are masked. The number after the slash is CIDR notation and represents a mask address which, combined with the address before the slash, is used to represent a range of addresses.

- the "**/32**" will mask all 32 bits of the address effectively meaning a **range of 1 single IP address** , eg. 282.72.129.**206** -> 282.72.129.**206**
- the "**/31**" will only mask first 31 bits of the address, meaning that the last bit can either by 0 or 1 and resulting in a **range of two addresses**:  282.72.129.**206** -> 282.72.129.**207**

A couple of slightly more in depth, easy to understand articles:

http://www.enterprisenetworkingplanet.com/netsp/article.php/3566521/Networking-101-Understanding-Subnets-and-CIDR.htm

http://phpfunk.com/uncategorized/cidr-notation-explained-simply/

Answer (score 1):

/32 is just that IP, /31 is usually used in Point to Point links as broadcast in those sort of networks is not necessary.